# heroku cli spawns infinite number of processes

Tags: heroku-cli

I was using heroku cli today again after a week or so and it crashed my system. Turns out it recursively spawns a huge amount of processes:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
...
myUserName   10112 10106  0 14:19 pts/5    00:00:00 bash /home/myUserName/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku
myUserName   10118 10112  0 14:19 pts/5    00:00:00 bash /home/myUserName/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku
myUserName   10124 10118  0 14:19 pts/5    00:00:00 bash /home/myUserName/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku
myUserName   10130 10124  0 14:19 pts/5    00:00:00 bash /home/myUserName/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku
myUserName   10136 10130  0 14:19 pts/5    00:00:00 bash /home/myUserName/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku
...
```

This happens regardless of whether I invoke `/usr/local/bin/heroku` or `/usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku` directly. Trying to upgrade via

```
wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

I get the same effect.

Has anybody experienced the same or knows a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just deleting all heroku directories I found on my hard drive and then reinstalling via `wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`. This seems to have worked. I needed to redo a `heroku login` afterwards of course.